# Why is my css file not being used? Not showing the background image

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to develop a basic webpage with a background and some centered text but for some reason its not reading the css file and wont produce the background image.

Yes the css, html & background image are in the same folder.
And I'm using brackets IDE http://brackets.io/ (Shouldnt make a difference but yeah)

HTML Source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>  
            <title> Sample Page </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <div>
                    <h1>Developments</h1>
                    <h4>Most Beautiful Website</h4>
                </div>
            </header>
        </body>
    </html>
```

CSS Source

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{
    background-image: url(skyline.png);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Arial';
}

.header-content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me the folder structure of your css, images & files

Comment: I've got a folder on the desktop called Home which includes a style.css index.html & skyline.png

Comment: Are all these three files on the same folder, without any subfolders?

Comment: See that [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldgqctgr/) works fine, so there is no problem with your code. Check if your file names are the same, css is EXACTLY in the same folder as html, maybe cache clean?

Comment: Are you using a mac?

Answer (score 0):

The index.html had been relocated outside of the original folder to the desktop.
A simple relocation of the index.html to the original folder fixed the issue.